# How to load data from local realm db?

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

I have populated data from server in UI through realm and volley.
Is it possible to store that data locally and show in UI from local db? And how to do it?
Any example would be very helpful.Thanks.
Actually I am trying to get the data locally after fetching and populating the data from the server like this.

```
    if(realm!=null){
        Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "realm fetching");
        RealmResults<SellerProducts> sellerProductItems=realm.where(SellerProducts.class).findAll();

        adapter.setData(sellerProductItems);
        adapter.notifyDataUpdate();
    }else {
         //network fetch operation 
         // getting data 
         //populating data like this
         sellerProductItems= gson.fromJson(products.toString(), new TypeToken<List<SellerProducts>>(){}.getType());
            //Products is from server response
            realm.beginTransaction();
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(sellerProductItems);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            adapter.setData(sellerProductItems);
            adapter.notifyDataUpdate();   
     }
```

Is it correct?

Comment: you should refer realm [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/). It covers all the details

Comment: This sounds conceptually wrong to me, like how can you even have `realm == null` in your code, not to mention you're completely disregarding what thread you're executing the network operation on or querying from the realm

Answer (score 1):

To save data in realm create a realm object and do Transaction like this

```
myRealm.beginTransaction();

// Create an object
Country country1 = myRealm.createObject(Country.class); 
country1.setName("Norway");
country1.setPopulation(5165800);
country1.setCode("NO");
myRealm.commitTransaction();
```

To read the data saved

```
RealmResults<Country> results1 =
    myRealm.where(Country.class).findAll();
for(Country c:results1) {
Log.d("results1", c.getName());
}
```

For complete information visit 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/up-and-running-with-realm-for-android--cms-25241

Comment: Aakash,i have edited my question, is it correct or not ?i think first time network fetch operation executed and after it when the network is gone it should fetch it from realm.am i correct or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No, you're completely wrong. If you're doing it right, `realm` can never be `null` at that point in your code.

Anyways it works vaguely like this (based on [this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html)):

```
public class GsonRequest<T extends RealmObject> extends Request<T> {
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private final Listener<T> listener;

    /**
     * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
     *
     * @param url URL of the request to make
     */
    public GsonRequest(Method method, String url, 
            Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json = new String(
                    response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            final List<T> result = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {}.getType());
            Realm realm = null;
            try {
                realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration); //get realm config
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    for(T t : result) {
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(t);
                    }        
                });
            } finally {
                if(realm != null) {
                    realm.close();
                }
            }
            return Response.success(null, //returning null because 
                                          //Realm handles all reload of data on UI thread
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
Realm realm;
RealmResults<SellerProducts> results;
final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<SellerProducts>> realmChangeListener;

SellerProductsAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
    results = realm.where(SellerProducts.class).findAll();
    realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<SellerProducts>>() {
         @Override
         public void onChange(RealmResults<SellerProducts> element) {
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.retrofit_is_better_than_volley);
    ListView whyIsThisNotRecyclerView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.not_recycler_for_some_reason_view);
    adapter = new SellerProductsAdapter(this, results);
    whyIsThisNotRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(results != null && results.isValid()) {
        results.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }
    if(realm != null) {
        realm.close();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And then something like

```
GsonRequest<SellerProducts> request = new GsonRequest(Method.GET, url, 
     new Response.Listener<SellerProducts>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(SellerProducts nullObject) {
             // hide dialog or something
         }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() { 
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage()/*, exception? */);
             // hide dialog or something
         }
     });

//add to request queue
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to bring Realm to your production code, it takes more than what is discussed here, Realm is a major library and there are also some limitations like Realm, RealmObject and RealmResults can not be passed across threads.

To solve this problem, you need a good architecture, where Realm is isolated from rest of the code. Create a realmModel for each jsonModel and a DAO (Data Access Object). All Realm related calculations should be part of DAO, so that none of your code base needs to know about Realm.

Here is an article about Realm best practices with a good architechture https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/realm-integration-in-android-best-practices-449919d25f2f

Also a sample project demonstrating Integration of Realm on Android with MVP(Model View Presenter), RxJava, Retrofit, Dagger, Annotations & Testing. https://github.com/viraj49/Realm_android-injection-rx-test